# How to teach to an adult person that is not used to study?

Tags: teaching

I'm trying to teach some basic things to my mother, such history, basic math and basic physics so she can attend a test.

But because of my mothers personality this has become pretty hard , since she has been influenced from the childhood by sayings  like "I can't study and can't learn", and trash like that.

This is so obnoxious , because to learn a small thing (v.gr.: add fractions) she takes a lot of time (2 or 3 hours) and the next day when trying to recall it, she don't solve the same problems of the day before and she fall in despair and trow out what already learn and stop to study.

I don't think the problem is some kind of disability, I'd rather say she can recall perfect it, but I have seen too that she doubts almost of all the things she knows, and don't write a thing because before she write down something, she believes its wrong!!!

I think too she has a hard time trying to focus on the themes explained.
I have exhausted each idea about trying to explain things: cardboards, games, using the videos of youtube, reading along the books, talking about the themes instead of a serious lecture.

Of course I'm aware I'm not a teacher, but whats does really matter is that she learn a bit of things, that's all.

This is more of pedagogy, but since there is no stack for that I have come here to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of test is she trying to learn to take? This sounds like an odd combination of subjects. Especially for (presumably) middle aged people to be taking.

Comment: Is she studying to get something like the GED (high school equivalent in the US)? What country is she in? In the US, school districts often have adult schools that can help someone prepare.

Comment: I'm somehow amazed by the title of your question because, well, university students _are_ adult people.

Comment: The [Mathematics Educators Site](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) might be the better community for this, if you focus on teaching math to your mother.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano And yet everyone understood that this was about someone who has left school and university for a while already. Funny how that works huh?

Comment: @user2357 Indeed it works. My comment, which was not meant to be rude, was about the original title. But, most of all, it was a way to point out that sometimes here we tend to think at university students as kids.

Answer (score 4):

Life is dependent many times on being motivated to succeed. There is not a magical formula for having no motivation and yet having success. If your mother cannot find the motivation to learn, it is rather hard to force learning down her throat. If you can make learning matter to her, she will want to learn.

Perhaps you should look into hiring a professional tutor if your mother needs to learn this material for her employment (or the like). Removing the family element could allow for her to feel more motivation. In certain countries, there are programs for adult learning. One can obtain an equivalent to basic high school education from these programs.